# How can I place elements between sections using CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I've looking for a way to place elements between sections, I tried using margins but the elements stay "behind" the next section in the page. What's the CSS property I need to use? I use Tailwind CSS but would like to know what property handles it so I can look about it in the documentation. Also, I'm using components (React / JSX) in my project.

I attached an image for reference.

Thanks!

[Elements inside red square][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVLbS.png

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on writing a post that best enables the community to provide assistance.  Please note that for a question like this it is generally expected you provide a [mcve] as code in the question body, as well as any steps to reproduce the issue, the expected behavior, and the actual behavior.  Without providing any code it will be challenging for visitors to this post to provide you with specific guidance.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

[try codes below in TailwindCSS playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/)
hope u get what u want

```html
    <div class="bg-sky-400">
    <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-indigo-400">
    <div class="absolute z-10 -translate-y-1/2">
    <div class="inline-block h-4 w-4 rounded-full bg-white"></div>
    <div class="inline-block h-4 w-4 rounded-full bg-white"></div>
    </div>
    <p>hello</p>
    </div>
```